# Threads leak in Java application - causing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, memory-leaks

Some context: Running a SpringBoot Java process, with `'-Xms128m -Xmx4000m -Xss256k'`.
Application is complicated and cannot paste it here (many objects and logics). The application is running 24/7, and most of her job is using `@Scheduled` methods. Every few weeks we are getting: `Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread”` and our server also cannot allow SSH connection (probably memory is full from this leak).

I've found that probably I have a threads leak, growing each day by ~2000 threads, that keeps being on the RUNNABLE state. Example of this kind of thread:

```
"I/O dispatcher 3150" #38743 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff48f748000 nid=0x38d runnable [0x00007ff482f0b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000006da140f98> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000006da140f88> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000006da140e50> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:257)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Anyone have an idea what is this kind of threads and how to eliminate this leak?

Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing which task executor/scheduler you are using and your thread config this isn't going to lead to an answer. One thing make sure you aren't creating threads yourself.

Comment: I have only one place that I'm using: ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
        builder.start();

Comment: Which is creating a new thread (apparently a deamon one). Why do that if you are  you scheduler?

Comment: I need to execute an external process (some ssh to other server)

Comment: The `@Scheduled` already runs on a special/seperate thread, why would you need another one? If you really want this then at least create a `TaskExecutor` with a fixed amount of threads, make your `ProcessBuilder` a `Runnable` (not a `Thread`) and pass it to the `TaskExecutor` which will use one of its threads to execute the task. Don't start new threads as that will lead to thease kind of issues. Also as mentioned please add at least the relevant code, stating that it is too large, isn't helpful and the key lies in your config and code.